# Canvas.scale - выходные данные равны нулю, в чем проблема?

Tags: android

Использую canvas.scale для оптимизации игрового поля в своей игре, но столкнулся с проблемой - canvas.scale(x,y) x и y = 0, поэтому и на экране ничего не отображается, хотя по-логике должно быть значение с точкой. Как можно решить данную проблему?

Вот код:`public  class Game extends Activity {

```
public static int heightDisplay;
public static int widthDisplay;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new GamePanel(this));

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);

    heightDisplay = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    widthDisplay = displaymetrics.widthPixels;


}
```

}`

```
public static final int WIDTH = 720;
public static final int HEIGHT = 1280;

  @Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas)
{

    if(canvas!=null) {
        final int savedState = canvas.save();
        canvas.scale(Game.widthDisplay/WIDTH, Game.heightDisplay/HEIGHT);
        bg.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restoreToCount(savedState);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Точка бесконечно мала, вот и не отображается)

Comment: как это бесконечно мала?Если проводить эти же действия через калькулятор показывает разумные числа(0,8,0,5 и т.п)

Comment: вы же сами написали что `x и y = 0`

Comment: Да, я выводил через логи, а там все по нулям, хотя там не может получится ноль никаким образом

Comment: Ну если бы действительно не мог, то не получился бы. Так что ищите ошибку там.